# Trying to get 100% in ssllabs.com key exchange

Tags: ssl, https, apache2, lets-encrypt

I wanted to know what steps are needed to get 100% on every category in ssllabs.com. I am aware that this could lead to problems in older systems,  but I dont care.

My letsencrypt.org certificate uses 4096 bits. This is the best score I could get using the following config:

```
SSLCipherSuite AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLProtocol all -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1 -SSLv3 -SSLv2
```

[image: score before adding DHParameters]

I read [somewhere](https://michael.lustfield.net/nginx/getting-a-perfect-ssl-labs-score) that the key exchange could be improved using a pregenerated dhparam file.

So I generated this file using `openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 4096` (this took around a hour) and added it to my apache configuration using

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters "/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem"
```

but this results in the same score as before. So what am I missing here?

[Full ssllabs.com result](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=brunner.ninja)

Comment: Do not optimize for benchmarks. If you want to deploy the latest reasonably achievable security level, get an EC 384 bit certificate, roll out public key pinning and examine if `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck` is useful to your setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of 2017-10, if you are using Diffie-Hellman, you ought to have **both DH parameters *and* keys with equivalent 4096 bits RSA**.

*You are offering atleast one certificate for a 2048 bit key. You are also having unusual metadata in that certificate, check that (the default snake-oil certificate for saying "i dont serve non-sni clients" generally only has the host name in `Common Name`)*

**Edit:** You will not be penalized in the SSL Labs rating for certificates that you exclusively offer no non-SNI clients. You will also not penalized for weak-keyed certificates you provide as part of your certificate chain to a known root.

[You will find the full documentation on the rating on the *ssllabs* github account.](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide)

> For suites that rely on DHE or ECDHE key exchange, the strength of DH
>   parameters is taken into account when determining the strength of the
>   handshake as a whole. Many servers that support DHE use DH parameters
>   that provide 1024 bits of security. On such servers, the strength of
>   the key exchange will never go above 1024 bits, even if the private
>   key is stronger (usually 2048 bits).

The rating guide doesnt say, but i was able to confirm that you cannot get rating 100 if your server prefers `secp256v1` (equivalent to 3k bits RSA) while offering ECDHE ciphers that could be using `secp384v1` (equivalent to 7k bits RSA).

```
Chrome 57 / Win 7
R
RSA 4096 (SHA256)
TLS 1.2 > http/1.1
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384   
ECDH secp256r1  FS
```

The Apache manual does list one option to force this (simply ordering the `Curves` parameter by strength appears to be insufficient)

> Compatibility:    Available in httpd 2.4.8 and later, if using OpenSSL 1.0.2 or later
>   SSLOpenSSLConfCmd ECDHParameters brainpoolP256r1

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslopensslconfcmd

If you name a curve here that can be considered equivalent to RSA >=4096 bits, ssl labs will be using that for your ECDHE ciphers - listing you the clients that can no longer succeed a handshake with your server because they do not support that curve.

[image: secp384r1 will grant 100%]

**Carefully investigate the list of browsers you wish to support, choosing a non-standard EC curve *will* make your site inaccessible by many older browsers!**

Comment: I am not sure why my apache keeps sending out my "localhost" certificate. I am using virtualhosts and if a domain is not found in the config, the first one is selected instead. So I made a "fallback" virtualhost first (this one has the localhost cert).

Comment: I just replaced the snakeoil one with a 16384bit long one. But still on change in points...