# Trying to get 100% in ssllabs.com key exchange with nginx (Oct/2022)

Tags: nginx, ssl, public-key

My site got A+ on all score fields, however, it seems ssllabs.com changed some measures, and the key exchange score is not 100% any more:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INxfk.png)

My previous Nginx setting is like this:

```
          ssl_protocols     TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
          ssl_ciphers       ECDH+AESGCM+AES256:ECDH+CHACHA20; # TLSv1.2
          ssl_conf_command  Ciphersuites TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256; # TLSv1.3
          ssl_ecdh_curve    secp384r1;
```

I already studied the [old question](https://serverfault.com/questions/877774/trying-to-get-100-in-ssllabs-com-key-exchange), but it seems the settings are outdated and not working anymore. So how to get the key exchange reaches 100% score in 2022?

Comment: You need to show the detail output from the test in order for us to see what is not optimal.